# how to disable editing of a tableview in storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a tableview which shows no "Edit" button in the storyboard but shows it in the emulator. I want to disable editing for the table view using the storyboard, how?

Answer (score 0):

On the left lower side there is a little button to open a sidebar, do this. Then select the UITableView and on the right side in the properties set userEditingEnabled to No or whatever it says.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I selected the table view and clicked on the Attributes Inspector button. But I can't find the option for disabling user editing.